# error in python : index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python

Today i want to learn about how to code a content based filtering in python, and so i search some code and i apply it. I have a simple dataset contains a hotel dataset, with the name, address, and description. After i tried the code, its said index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 at the end of the code. Here's the code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
import random

data = pd.read_csv('hotel.csv')
data.head()
```

the output :
nama    alamat  deskripsi
0   Capital O 253 Topas Galeria Hotel   Jl. Dr. Djundjunan No. 153, 40173 Bandung, Ind...   Berjarak 10 menit berkendara dari Bandara Inte...
1   Sheraton Bandung Hotel & Towers Jl. Ir H Juanda 390, 40135 Bandung, Indonesia   Sheraton Hotel & Towers menawarkan akomodasi b...
2   OYO 794 Ln 9 Bandung Residence  Jalan Lemahnendeut No 9, Sukajadi, 40164 Bandu...   Berlokasi nyaman di Sukajadi, Bandung, OYO 794...
3   OYO 226 LJ hotel    Jl. Malabar No.2, Malabar, Lengkong, Dago, Asi...   OYO 226 LJ hotel di Bandung, Jawa Barat, tepat...
4   OYO 230 Maleo Residence JI. Dangeur Indah II No. 15, Sukagalih, Sukaja...   OYO 230 Maleo Residence menawarkan akomodasi b...

```
data.describe()
data.info()
```

the output :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 90 entries, 0 to 89
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------     --------------  ----- 
 0   nama       90 non-null     object
 1   alamat     90 non-null     object
 2   deskripsi  90 non-null     object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 2.2+ KB
```

---

```
clean_spcl = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
clean_symbol = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
stopworda = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower() 
    text = clean_spcl.sub(' ', text)
    text = clean_symbol.sub('', text)
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in stopworda) # hapus stopword dari kolom deskripsi
    return text
  
data['deskripsi_new'] = data['deskripsi'].apply(clean_text)

def pt_desc(index):
    example = data[data.index == index][['deskripsi_new', 'nama', 'alamat']].values[0]
    if len(example) > 0:
        print(example[0])
        print('Nama:', example[1])
        print('Alamat:', example[2])   

data.set_index('nama', inplace=True)
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(data['deskripsi_new'])
cos_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
cos_sim
```

the output :

```
array([[1.        , 0.07106689, 0.03075961, ..., 0.07474134, 0.0732575 ,
        0.01680878],
       [0.07106689, 1.        , 0.03508807, ..., 0.05947269, 0.08705608,
        0.01986701],
       [0.03075961, 0.03508807, 1.        , ..., 0.09113962, 0.05879732,
        0.06808138],
       ...,
       [0.07474134, 0.05947269, 0.09113962, ..., 1.        , 0.06321301,
        0.02205802],
       [0.0732575 , 0.08705608, 0.05879732, ..., 0.06321301, 1.        ,
        0.02245328],
       [0.01680878, 0.01986701, 0.06808138, ..., 0.02205802, 0.02245328,
        1.        ]])

indices = pd.Series(data.index)
indices[:50]

def rekomendasi(nama, cos_sim = cos_sim):
    
    rec = []
    
    idx = indices[indices == nama].index[0]

    score_series = pd.Series(cos_sim[idx]).sort_values(ascending = False)

    top_10_indexes = list(score_series.iloc[1:11].index)
    
    for i in top_10_indexes:
        recommended_news.append(list(data.index)[i])
        
    return rec

rekomendasi('Hotel') # and when i reach here, the error said 'index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'
```

what went wrong here?

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful. It looks like none of the indices equal `'Hotel'`.

Comment: @HansMusgrave I use all words related to description, or the address, but it still shows the same error

Comment: Do `data.describe()` and `data.info()` output useful information about your data? If so, please [edit] your question and copy and paste that output into it, so that everyone has that information.

Comment: in this line ```idx = indices[indices == nama].index[0]``` it will be like this ```idx = indices[indices == 'Hotel'].index[0]```. Is that what you are expecting?. Because if "Hotel" is not in indices you will get the error.

Comment: can you past the whole error traceback, and if possible share the sample data you used, because without the data to reproduce your problem it's difficult to tell which line exactly is causing the problem

Comment: @Alka ok, maybe u can see it in my github : https://github.com/dannyambarita/Content-Based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to build a kind of search engine, which given a search vector will return the 10 best matching results.

If this is the case, you'll need to modify your `rekomendasi` function so that it will :

- process the input query vector
- compute the similarity scores with the corpus (corpus here mean the list of your hotel descriptions)
- return the 10 items with highest similarity scores

I've modified your code to do that :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
import random

data = pd.read_csv('../../../../Downloads/hotel.csv')

clean_spcl = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
clean_symbol = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
stopworda = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower() 
    text = clean_spcl.sub(' ', text)
    text = clean_symbol.sub('', text)
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in stopworda) # hapus stopword dari kolom deskripsi
    return text
  
data['deskripsi_new'] = data['deskripsi'].apply(clean_text)

def pt_desc(index):
    example = data[data.index == index][['deskripsi_new', 'nama', 'alamat']].values[0]
    if len(example) > 0:
        print(example[0])
        print('Nama:', example[1])
        print('Alamat:', example[2])   

data.set_index('nama', inplace=True)
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 3), min_df=0, stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(data['deskripsi_new'])
cos_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
cos_sim

def rekomendasi(nama, cos_sim=cos_sim):
    
    # you first need to preprocess the given query text (i.e. nama) and transform it in tf=idf vector
    nama = clean_text(nama)
    nama_vector = tf.transform([nama])
    
    # Next we compute similarity scores between the query text (nama) and the corpus (tfidf_matrix)
    similarity_scores = cosine_similarity(nama_vector, tfidf_matrix).squeeze()
    top_10_indices = similarity_scores.argsort()[-10:][::-1]
    
    rec = data.index[top_10_indices].tolist()
    return rec
```

Example :

```py
rekomendasi('Hotel')
```

`['The Trans Luxury Hotel Bandung', 'M Premiere Hotel Dago Bandung', 'Mutiara Hotel', 'éL Hotel Royale Bandung', 'The Jayakarta Suites Bandung, Hotel & Spa', 'Hotel Cemerlang', "OYO 167 Dago's Hill Hotel", "OYO 167 Dago's Hill Hotel", 'HARRIS Hotel & Conventions Ciumbuleuit – Bandung', 'Padma Hotel Bandung']`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I just tried it and it worked.